# Cannot connect to Snowflake using Python Connector and extrernalbrowser authenticator

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to connect to Snowflake using Python connector and SSO. I am expecting the connector to open a browser to authenticate the user but this isn't working:

```
h:\Code\bin>python conn.py
Initiating login request with your identity provider. A browser window should have opened for you to complete the login. If you can't see it, check existing browser windows, or your OS settings. Press CTRL+C to abort and try again...
```

A browser window never pops up, and instead I get the following straight away

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conn.py", line 9, in <module>
    authenticator='externalbrowser'
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\__init__.py", line 53, in Connect
    return SnowflakeConnection(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 187, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 484, in connect
    self.__open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 699, in __open_connection
    self.__authenticate(auth_instance)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\connection.py", line 922, in __authenticate
    password=self._password,
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\auth_webbrowser.py", line 104, in authenticate
    authenticator, service_name, account, callback_port, user)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\auth_webbrowser.py", line 305, in _get_sso_url
    socket_timeout=self._rest._connection.login_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\network.py", line 530, in _post_request
    _include_retry_params=_include_retry_params)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\network.py", line 609, in fetch
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\network.py", line 711, in _request_exec_wrapper
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\network.py", line 653, in _request_exec_wrapper
    method, full_url, headers, data, conn)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\network.py", line 758, in _handle_unknown_error
    u'errno': ER_FAILED_TO_REQUEST,
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py", line 100, in errorhandler_wrapper
    connection.errorhandler(connection, cursor, errorclass, errorvalue)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\errors.py", line 73, in default_errorhandler
    done_format_msg=errorvalue.get(u'done_format_msg'))
snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: 250003: Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://<ACCOUNT>:443/session/authenticator-request?request_guid=<guid>
```

The script:

```
import snowflake.connector
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='XXXX',
    password='XXXX',
    account='My account>',
    warehouse='DEMO_WH',
    database='DEV',
    schema='TPCH_SF1000',
    authenticator='externalbrowser'
)
```

```
>python --version
Python 3.6.5
>>pip3 list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
agate (1.6.1)
asn1crypto (1.3.0)
attrs (19.3.0)
azure-common (1.1.25)
azure-core (1.7.0)
azure-storage-blob (2.1.0)
azure-storage-common (2.1.0)
Babel (2.8.0)
boto3 (1.11.17)
botocore (1.14.17)
cachetools (4.1.1)
certifi (2020.6.20)
cffi (1.13.2)
chardet (3.0.4)
colorama (0.4.3)
cryptography (2.9.2)
cx-Oracle (8.0.0)
dataclasses (0.6)
dbt (0.17.0)
dbt-bigquery (0.17.0)
dbt-core (0.17.0)
dbt-postgres (0.17.0)
dbt-redshift (0.17.0)
dbt-snowflake (0.17.0)
decorator (4.4.2)
docutils (0.15.2)
google-api-core (1.16.0)
google-auth (1.19.0)
google-cloud-bigquery (1.24.0)
google-cloud-core (1.3.0)
google-resumable-media (0.5.1)
googleapis-common-protos (1.6.0)
hologram (0.0.7)
idna (2.8)
ijson (2.6.1)
importlib-metadata (1.7.0)
isodate (0.6.0)
Jinja2 (2.11.2)
jmespath (0.10.0)
json-rpc (1.13.0)
jsonschema (3.1.1)
leather (0.3.3)
Logbook (1.5.3)
MarkupSafe (1.1.1)
minimal-snowplow-tracker (0.0.2)
msrest (0.6.17)
networkx (2.4)
oauthlib (3.1.0)
oscrypto (1.2.0)
parsedatetime (2.6)
pip (9.0.3)
protobuf (3.11.3)
psycopg2-binary (2.8.5)
pyasn1 (0.4.8)
pyasn1-modules (0.2.8)
pycparser (2.20)
pycryptodomex (3.9.8)
PyJWT (1.7.1)
pyOpenSSL (19.1.0)
pyrsistent (0.16.0)
python-dateutil (2.8.1)
python-slugify (4.0.1)
pytimeparse (1.1.8)
pytz (2020.1)
PyYAML (5.3.1)
requests (2.22.0)
requests-oauthlib (1.3.0)
rsa (4.6)
s3transfer (0.3.3)
setuptools (39.0.1)
six (1.15.0)
snowflake-connector-python (2.2.1)
sqlparse (0.3.1)
text-unidecode (1.3)
typing-extensions (3.7.4.2)
urllib3 (1.25.9)
Werkzeug (0.16.1)
zipp (3.1.0)
```

I can confirm that I can connect with Perl using DBD::ODBC, so the externalbrowser authenticator works in principle, but I'm just not sure why it isn't for Python

Comment: Are you passing the account name with region? If possible could you please share the account name you are passing in the python script

Comment: While authenticating snowflake using external browser no need to mention the password. Could you please share the account and user name how you are passing in your python code?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really want to share my account name in a public forum. As with password, user isn't relevant as it's determined in the SSO, but it's a mandatory field. Again, as with the account, I don't want to share my username in a public forum. As I mentioned, I can connect with Perl and ODBC with the exact same values.

Comment: It does seem odd that this is only occurring for Python on the same system; it seems like this would rule out a potential networking issue but I don't like to rule anything out yet.  I'm going to throw a few investigative questions at you.  Can you connect to Snowflake just using regular username/password with Python (rules out account name issue)?   Possible to upgrade Snowflake Python driver to the latest and try again? Can you see anything blocking browser? Can you try SnowCD and see if all tests pass? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html#snowcd-connectivity-diagnostic-tool

Comment: Multiple python libraries were in the path. When the old paths were removed, problem disappeared. Thanks

Comment: @DanHorne Could you please elaborate on your answer? Which path are you referring to? The env. var path?